# nix installation error; GLIBC_2.33 not found

Tags: nix

trying to install nix (on a clean fedora 35 server), getting this error!

**Error message:**

> /nix/store/sbbifs2ykc05inws26203h0xwcadnf0l-glibc-2.32-46/lib/libc.so.6:
> version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by
> /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23)

****my version of libc;****

ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.34

Comment: The dynamic linker is picking up at least one library from `/usr`, which it shouldn't. Could you run `env | grep LD_` and add the output to the question text?

Comment: was in a hurry so wiped fedora and installed ubuntu, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env which tells nix to load `/usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23` which has the wrong glibc version.